# How to make an element's content editable with JavaScript (or jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

How would I make it so the content of an element could be made editable through native JavaScript (DOM) and/or jQuery?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Solution to toggle editable on/off using a click handler:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var $div=$('div'), isEditable=$div.is('.editable');
    $div.prop('contenteditable',!isEditable).toggleClass('editable')
})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Wu4VD/)**</kbd>

Comment: @Jamen it's really not hard to convert it. try it and if you have problems create another question

Answer (score 33):

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('elementId').contentEditable = 'true';
```

Answer (score 14):

Look at this example i've made:
http://jsfiddle.net/K6W7J/

JS:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('div').attr('contenteditable','true');
})
```

HTML:

```
<button>CLICK</button>
<div>YOUR CONTENT</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [this](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html)  plugin which i have been with no problem any time. it is realy simple 
and easy to use.

Here an example:

**Html:**

```
 <div style="margin: 150px">
    <a href="#" id="username">awesome</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 $('#username').editable({
        type: 'text',
        url: '/post',    
        pk: 1,    
        title: 'Enter username',
        ajaxOptions: {
            type: 'put'
        }        
    });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/38/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery to add the attribute to the element you should be able to switch between edit mode and 'normal' HTML mode. The contenteditable attribute is supported by all major browsers. Check out http://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-contenteditable for more information.

Comment: original link is still there, but all the links therein are now defunct. :(

Answer (score 0):

All we have to do is set the **contenteditable** attribute on nearly any HTML element to make it editable.

Here's a simple example which creates a  element whose contents the user can **edit.**

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  This text can be edited by the user.
</div>
```