# contenteditable not working in accordian

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

here, I have code that enables dragging and dropping of accordian. 
But what I want is when User clicks on edit, then content in accordian should be editable.
I have tried the answers from following link [How to make an element's content editable with JavaScript (or jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830353/how-to-make-html-content-editable-with-javascript-jquery). But not getting the result i want.

The script is:

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src=" http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $('#accordion').accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    height: 'fill',
    header: 'h3'
}).sortable({
    items: '.s_panel'
});

$('#accordion').on('accordionactivate', function (event, ui) {
    if (ui.newPanel.length) {
        $('#accordion').sortable('disable');
    } else {
        $('#accordion').sortable('enable');
    }
    });



$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
    connectWith : ".sortable"
});
});

</script>
<script>
$('#btn1').click(function () {
$('#content1').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
});

</script>

</head>
```

The HTML is:

```
<body>
<br /><br />
<div id="source" style="width:345px;float:left; border:1px dotted ">
<div id="accordion" style="height:450px;width:300px; " class="sortable">
    <div class="s_panel">
         <h3 class="ui-state-default unassigned">About Us</h3>
              <div id="data">
                   <div id="content1">This is about Us</div>
                         <form> 
                         <input id="bt1" type="button" value="edit"/>
                         </form>
              </div>
    </div>


</div>
</div>
<div id="teams" style=" position:absolute; top: 100px; left:400px; width:600px;" >
<ul class="sortable" style="height:450px;width:550px; "></ul>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: How abt creating a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Anup...what was that? a blank fiddle?

Comment: I was suggesting you to create a fiddle.

Comment: @Anup http://jsfiddle.net/bh2Kn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PvkKK/)

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    $('#content1').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
});

<input id="btn" type="button" value="edit" />
```

New Edited :-

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
        connectWith : ".sortable"
    });
```

[FIDDLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ySZwL/)

Comment: mate, you made the text in the accordian editable, but my drag n drop functionality is lost in your fiddle.

Comment: and what i m achieving is still the same i.e uneditable. But drag n drop still be done.

Comment: There is still 1 problem in new fiddle.

Comment: thank you for the answer..it works perfectly in the fiddle.. But is not working as an output in my browser. I am using Chrome.

Comment: Try removing `<script src=" http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>` this script.

Comment: there are no errors...but still I am working upon it.. oll functionalities are correct except that editing part. It works perfectly in fiddle.. anyways thanks for your time.