# JQuery Toggle property contentEditable = "true"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using contenteditable="true" in a div

What I want to do it to toggle true and false on this attribute everytime I click on a div.

example:

```
$( "#mylabel" ).click(function() {
    $('#editablediv').attr('contenteditable','false');
});
```

I tried:

```
$( "#mylabel" ).toggle(function() {
    $('#editablediv').attr('contenteditable','false');
});
```

but that didn't work

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Make HTML Content Editable with JavaScript / jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830353/how-to-make-html-content-editable-with-javascript-jquery)

Comment: It works ,try http://jsfiddle.net/jxfxM/1/

Comment: FYI ... The example on possible duplicate is not correct as that example toggles a class ... I need to toggle an attrible so it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$( "#mylabel" ).click(function() {
    var value = $('#editablediv').attr('contenteditable');

    if (value == 'false') {
        $('#editablediv').attr('contenteditable','true');
    }
    else {
        $('#editablediv').attr('contenteditable','false');
    }
});
```

Keep me posted, hope this helped

Answer (score 2):

Here is shorter than your shortest (Reusability and Character Count):

```
function editTheElement() {
    var a = "contenteditable";
    $(this).attr(a) === 'true' ? $(this).attr(a,'false') : $(this).attr(a, 'true');
}
```

or still

```
function editTheElement(e) {
    var a = "contenteditable";
    e.attr(a) === 'true' ? e.attr(a,'false') : e.attr(a, 'true');
}
```

or

```
function editTheElement(e) {
    var a = 'contenteditable';
    var v= e.attr(a);
    e.attr(a,!v);
}
```

or

```
function editTheElement(e) {
    var a = 'contenteditable';
    e.attr(a,!e.attr(a));
}
```

or

```
function editTheElement(e) {
    e.attr('contenteditable',!e.attr('contenteditable'));
}
```

JS is fun :)

Answer (score 2):

In 2018 at least, most of these answers aren't working past the first on/off in Chrome 68. It's something with how jQuery or the browser is reading the value of this attribute, because the logic is pretty simple.

The code I found to work was

```
var el = $("{your selector}")
(el.attr('contenteditable') ?
  el.removeAttr('contenteditable') :
  el.attr('contenteditable', true));
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gwkz8Lu/12/)

Answer (score 0):

shortest solution I found:

```
$('[contenteditable]').attr('contenteditable') === 'true' ? 
$('[contenteditable]').attr('contenteditable', 'false') : 
$('[contenteditable]').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mylabel').click(function() {
    editable = $('#editablediv').attr('contenteditable');
    $('#editablediv').attr('contenteditable', !(editable == 'true'));
});
```