# How do I create editable content in HTML

Tags: html, edit

How do I create editable content in HTML. That is, if I want to give an edit button for a section and on clicking the button make the content in the section readable. Sort of like how you can edit your posts on quora.

for example if we use the tag.

div contentEditable="true"

if you click on the content the content can be changed. But I want the content to be changed only when I click the edit button.

PS: I am new to HTML.

Comment: What do you mean? Something like a CMS system for you website or what?

Comment: You mean like using a server and a database to store and get information?

Comment: No like here when you click add comments an edit box appears and you can add comment right. Like that I want an edit box to appear when I click the edit button. This is not restricted to the developer alone. Anyone should be able to edit this if they have access to that page.

Comment: @HarikrishnanGNair Yeah, these comments are on the sever from a database. It's sever-sided programming. When you make a comment it's stored in the database and when users access this pages that information is retrieved from the database.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a markup language only. For advanced interaction on website must use languages such as PHP, ASP.NET or Javascript etc. I recommend you find something about open-source systems, which enable you to manage your website what you want.

**3 most popular CMS systems:**

- [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/)
- [Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/)
- [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/)

Comment: actually the thing is my site is a landing page containing links to other sites. I want to add an announcement div which should be editable by some one who doesnt have any html knowledge. For just one section going back to the drawing board seems like a bad idea. That is why I am trying to figure something out

Comment: You need a website when the user changes the contents to be stored somewhere (in the database), it can be done only and only using JavaScript (Ajax), or PHP, and stored in a database (MySQL etc.). HTML hasn't opportunity to offer what you are looking for.

Comment: oh..ok..Il try to find out more about that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pointer, though as suggested by @Mardzis' answer there is more to it.

```js
$('.editable').editable({event: 'click'})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/victorjonsson/jquery-editable/master/jquery.editable.min.js"></script>
<p class="editable">This is a simple paragraph</p>
```

This allows you to make anything editable.  If you need to *save* what you're editing, then I highly recommend investigating different backend solutions.  @Mardzis has offered some software solutions, you may also wish to investigate using PHP, node.js or similar.

For more JavaScript solutions, look here: [How to make an element's content editable with JavaScript (or jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830353/how-to-make-html-content-editable-with-javascript-jquery?rq=1)

Comment: I need to save the change. But thanks a lot for that response. That was really helpful.