# Text editing with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a simple product list. I want to implement the editing of a product.
When I double-click on the product, I will be able to edit it. But i dont understand how i can do this. I hope, that you understand me because english is not my primary language. My code is here:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Product List</h1>
    <input type="text" name="newProduct" id="newProduct" placeholder="Enter your product here"/>
    <ul id="productList"></ul>
    <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll"/><label for="Select all">Select all</label>
    <button id="deleteDoneProducts">Delete Selected</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
.container {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:600px;
}
h1, #newProduct {
    text-align: center;
    width:598px;
}
    #newProduct {
    border:1px solid #999;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 28px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #888;
}
#productList {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left:0;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
.product {
    padding: 15px 0px 15px 40px;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative; 
    font-size: 24px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #848484;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color:#000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.product:hover {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
.doneProduct {
    margin-right: 40px;
}
.remove {
    background-image: url(ico/delete_ico.png);
    background-position: 0 0;
    width:30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top:13px;   
    display: none;
}
.remove:hover {
    background-position: -34px 0px;
}
.product:hover .remove {
    display: block;
}
#deleteDoneProducts {
    float: right;
    background-color: #a3d5df; 
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
}
#deleteDoneProducts:hover {
    background-color: #5fb5c7;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

jquery

```
function addNewProduct(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        var toAdd = $('input[name=newProduct]').val();
             $('#productList').append('<li class="product"> <input     type="checkbox" class="doneProduct"/>'+toAdd+'<div class="remove"></div><li/>');
             $('#newProduct').val('');
             e.preventDefault();
    }
};

function deleteProduct() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
};


function productDone() {
    if (!$(this).is(":checked")){
        $(this).parent().css({'textDecoration': 'none', 'color': '#000'})
    } else  {
        $(this).parent().css({'textDecoration': 'line-through', 'color':     '#999'});
    };
};

function deleteAllSelected() {
    $(".doneProduct:checked").parent().remove();
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr("checked");
};

function selectAllProducts() {    
    if (!$(".doneProduct").is(":checked")) {
        $(".doneProduct").prop('checked', this.checked);
        $(".doneProduct").parent().css({'textDecoration': 'line-through',     'color': '#999'});

    } else {
        $(".doneProduct").parent().css({'textDecoration': 'none', 'color': '#000'});
        $(".doneProduct").prop('checked', this.checked);
    }

};                

$(function() {
     $("#newProduct").on('keypress', addNewProduct);
     $(document).on('click', ".remove", deleteProduct);
     $(document).on('change', ".doneProduct", productDone);
     $("#deleteDoneProducts").on('click', deleteAllSelected);
     $("#selectAll").on('click', selectAllProducts);
     $(".product").on('dbclick', editProductName);

})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qp3nnfc5/5/ - this is fiddle)

Answer (score 1):

Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qp3nnfc5/6/):

Change your addnewPRoduct function to:

```
function addNewProduct(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            var toAdd = $('input[name=newProduct]').val();
            $('#productList').append('<li class="product"> <input type="checkbox" class="doneProduct"/><span>'+toAdd+'</span><div class="remove"></div><li/>');
            $('#newProduct').val('');
            e.preventDefault();
        };
};
```

and Add this to your JS:

```
  $("#productList").on("dblclick","li",function(){
$(this).find('span').attr("contentEditable",true)
})
```

`Update :`

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qp3nnfc5/8/)

Add this to JS

```
$("#productList").on("keypress","li",function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
         e.preventDefault()
        $(this).find('span').attr("contenteditable",false)
        return;
    }
})
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830353/how-to-make-a-elements-content-editable-with-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: thanks. I have some question. How to complete the editing by pressing enter

Comment: @еленабондарчук: I have added an edit, please check it.