# How can I edit content in a html table

Tags: jquery, html

The following code sets a table:

```
gridSetup: function () {
                var self = this;
                $table = $('#csTable');
                trows = $($table).find('tbody tr');

                //0. IMPORTANT - clear table rows before re-building the table
                trows.remove();

                for (var x = 0; x < self.acYearCount; x++) {
                    var ay = x + 1;
                    //1. create a new row for each academic year
                    $tr = $('<tr class="cost-schedule ay' + [x + 1] + '"/>');
                    //2. create a new header
                    $th = $('<th class="horizontal">' + ay + '</th>');
                    //3. append header to row and row to table
                    $($table).append($($tr).append($th));
                    //4. add cells to current academic year row
                    for (var y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
                        $td = $('<td align="center"><input class="vertical" size="6" value="0"/></td>');                           
                        $($tr).append($td);
                    }
                }
            },
```

a button runs this:

```
editMe: function(){
                $("#hideAll input").attr("disabled", false);
                $("#hideAll select").attr("disabled", false);
```

These functions are found in vue.  When I click my button I want to be able to edit the created table.  I have tried putting contenteditable="false" in line  $td = $(''); of the grid setup with ("td").attr('contenteditable', true) in editMe.  None of this makes the created table structure editable on button click.  The lines found in editMe above makes the input above the created table editable.  Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you show us what your code is on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are many variants here:

[How do I make a div element editable (like a textarea when I click it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441565/how-do-i-make-a-div-element-editable-like-a-textarea-when-i-click-it)

another one [How to make an element's content editable with JavaScript (or jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830353/how-to-make-a-elements-content-editable-with-javascript-or-jquery)

ref from jQuery forum: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-and-contenteditable - they think that all must work in your sample...

Anyway try to do it with console in your browser prior to production.

1) Create single div#myid and try from console $("#myid").attr("contenteditable",true) - will it good? -not- check another browser - may be it's implemenation - defined

2) Create simple table with one tr /td#myid , repeat test

3) Try it with table tr + 2 td and with $('td') selector - can it make cells editable multiple?

If you will be sure that this way is valid and TDs became editable - return to your working code and check it again - what you forget.

Comment: Is it contenteditable or contentEditable I have seen it both ways in posts